# SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE chartered flight(flight_no NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY
, customer_id NUMBER(6) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
, aircraft_no NUMBER(4) REFERENCES aircraft(aircraft_no)
, flight_type VARCHAR2 (12)
, flight_date DATE NOT NULL
, flight_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND NOT NULL
, takeoff_at CHAR (3) NOT NULL
, destination CHAR (3) NOT NULL)
```

Should I not use CHAR data type?

I hear it is bad practice to use it but I wanted to make it so takeoff_at and destination have to have minimum 3 characters because they are airport codes.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:23
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Table name cannot have a space in it.

Comment: It is a bad practice to have spaces, but if you really want to have a space in the table name, you need to enclose it in double quotes. This will lead to more trouble later. However a statement that says TABLE NAME CANNOT HAVE SPACES is not exactly right.

This works:

create table "I love spaces"
(space_id integer, chartered_flight CHAR(10))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you're getting appears to be the result of the fact that there is no underscore between "chartered" and "flight" in the table name.  I assume you want something like this where the name of the table is `chartered_flight`.

```
CREATE TABLE chartered_flight(flight_no NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY
, customer_id NUMBER(6) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
, aircraft_no NUMBER(4) REFERENCES aircraft(aircraft_no)
, flight_type VARCHAR2 (12)
, flight_date DATE NOT NULL
, flight_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND NOT NULL
, takeoff_at CHAR (3) NOT NULL
, destination CHAR (3) NOT NULL)
```

Generally, there is no benefit to declaring a column as `CHAR(3)` rather than `VARCHAR2(3)`.  Declaring a column as `CHAR(3)` doesn't force there to be three characters of (useful) data.  It just tells Oracle to space-pad data with fewer than three characters to three characters.  That is unlikely to be helpful if someone inadvertently enters an incorrect code.  Potentially, you could declare the column as `VARCHAR2(3)` and then add a `CHECK` constraint that `LENGTH(takeoff_at) = 3`.

```
CREATE TABLE chartered_flight(flight_no NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY
, customer_id NUMBER(6) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
, aircraft_no NUMBER(4) REFERENCES aircraft(aircraft_no)
, flight_type VARCHAR2 (12)
, flight_date DATE NOT NULL
, flight_time INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND NOT NULL
, takeoff_at CHAR (3) NOT NULL CHECK( length( takeoff_at ) = 3 )
, destination CHAR (3) NOT NULL CHECK( length( destination ) = 3 )
)
```

Since both `takeoff_at` and `destination` are airport codes, you really ought to have a separate table of valid airport codes and define foreign key constraints between the `chartered_flight` table and this new `airport_code` table.  That ensures that only valid airport codes are added and makes it much easier in the future if an airport code changes.

And from a naming convention standpoint, since both `takeoff_at` and `destination` are airport codes, I would suggest that the names be complementary and indicate that fact.  Something like `departure_airport_code` and `arrival_airport_code`, for example, would be much more meaningful.

Comment: nice information very interesting but seeing as the airport code thing is just added by me and not in the coursework spec do you think I should add that in? I would have to change my ERD to match. Where would I add the CHECK constraint is that during the table creation?

Comment: @JatinderSingh - I added an example of declaring the `CHECK` constraints to the table definition (you can also add them afterwards in separate `ALTER TABLE` commands).  My bias would always be to do something correctly if you're going to do it which would entail adding the additional table if you're going to add airport codes to the `chartered_flight` table.  But, obviously, it's up to you to determine how much work you want to put in to an assignment, whether the instructor will care, and whether the extra work helps you learn anything.

Comment: OK say I was going to implement the separate table for airport codes then how would the two link? do I make departure_airport_code and arrival foreign keys of one column airport_code in the airport relation?

Comment: also would that relationship between charted flight and airport be a many to many type? would it need to be resolved? @Justin Cave

Comment: @JatinderSingh - You could either let `airport_code` be the primary key of the new `airport` table and create a foreign key constraint on both the `departure_airport_code` and `arrival_airport_code` columns or you could create a sequence-generated primary key on the `airport` table called `airport_id`, define the columns in `chartered_flight` to be `departure_airport_id` and `arrival_airport_id` and create the foreign key constraints.  The `airport_id` approach is more generic but if airport codes are more like state codes that never really change, using the code as the key is more practical.

Comment: YES if you look on the internet the codes are real codes they are static not something I want the database to create so I have made airport_code the PK

Answer (score 2):

there's nothing wrong with using CHAR like that.. 
I think your problem is that you have a space in your tablename. It should be: `charteredflight` or `chartered_flight`..

Answer (score 2):

You should not use space character while naming database objects. Even though it's possible by using double quotes(quoted identifiers), `CREATE TABLE "chartered flight" ...`, it's not recommended. Take a closer look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)